# Dapper Extension Class Mapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper, dapper-extensions

Table -1

```
Create Table GuestMessageDetails(

id bigint primary  key identity(1,1),
companyname  varchar(250),

FirstName   varchar(250),

FamilyName   varchar(250), 

EmialAdress   varchar(250),

Telephone   bigint,

Country   varchar(250),

ArticleNumber   varchar(250),


SoftwareVersion   varchar(250),

SerialNumber   varchar(250),

PurchaseDate varchar(250),

OrderNumber   varchar(250))
```

Table -2

```
Create Table ProductTable (Id bigint primary key identity(1,1),
ArticleImage    varchar(250),
ArticleNumber    Varchar(250))
```

model

```
 public class MessageModel
    {
        public string? companyname { get; set; }

        public string? FirstName { get; set; }

        public string? FamilyName { get; set; }

        public string? EmialAdress { get; set; }

        public long Telephone { get; set; }

        public string? Country { get; set; }

        public string? ArticleNumber {get;set;}

        public string? ArticleImage { get; set; }

        public string? SoftwareVersion { get; set; }

        public string? SerialNumber { get; set; }

         public  string? PurchaseDate { get; set; }

         public string? OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I Want Dapper Extension common two table  Class Mapper in Dapper Extension

how create Make Create Respository or Controller

I have Generic Repository Now I Want Two Table Common Generic Class Mapper

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map two tables with one Model (POCO/Entity) class. This is not supported by Dapper-Extensions.

Dapper-Extensions mapping is something like below:

```
public sealed class ProductMapper : ClassMapper<Product>
{
    public ProductMapper()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Products");
        Map(x => x.Id).Key(KeyType.Guid);
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

Observe that:

- the mapper class is derived from `ClassMapper<T>` where for `T` you provide your Model class.
- the `Table("Products");` call allows to input only one table name.

Dapper-Extensions is designed to generate simple queries for you which may reduce your 80-90% of the SQL code and make it reusable. For any complex scenario, you should fall-back to Dapper. Writing the query by hand helps best in those complex cases.

I am not sure whether creating View on SQL Server and mapping to it will help or not; it may not be practical solution as well.

If you want to use ORM for complex scenario as well, consider using full ORM like NHibernate.

Comment: I need Generic Class mapper ,I used in Generic Repository Now I need Generic Class Mapper for All Table